# Adding trend line to DT table

Tags: r, shiny

I have a data frame df. Is it possible to add a column (say "Trend") and show line graph showing values from Jan to Mar?

df

````
Col Jan Feb Mar
A   14  12  16
B   13  17  19
D   17  13  19
```
````

Comment: Two questions: 1) how is this question related to shiny, and 2) are the values you want to from a linear regression?

Comment: 1) Opps sorry my bad. It not shiny.  2) Not a linear one. Just values from Jan to Mar